# Powershell script exits on run time when Invoke-expression is executed

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to execute below code, when the run time hits the first invoke-expression , the script exit with out running the remaining code .ps1 file . This is happening in windows 7 with powershell v3. Any pointers here is appreciated. I have tried using Try{Invoke-expression ""} catch{ $_ }, but the logs show that script exit.

```
    $HardWares=@("abc","def")
    Write-Info ("Deleting device driver with $application")
    foreach ($HardWare in $HardWares){
        Write-Info ("working on hardware $HardWare")
        $DriverID = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnpSignedDriver | Where-Object {$_.hardwareID -eq $HardWare} | Select-Object InfName -ExpandProperty InfName | Select-Object -Unique)
        if ($DriverID){
            Write-Info ("Removing $HardWare and deleting $DriverID")
            $HardwareRemoveCmd = "D:\Users\App.exe remove $HardWare" 
            Invoke-Expression $HardwareRemoveCmd                              
            $Command= "D:\Users\App.exe dp_delete $DriverID -f"
            Invoke-Expression $Command
        } else {Write-Info "Could not find $DriverID file for $HardWare"}
    }
```

Comment: The property returned by `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnpSignedDriver` is `HardWareID` not `HardWare` so change your where to `Where-Object 
  {$_.HardWareID -eq $HardWare}`

Comment: Its a Typo , I was actually checking for hardwareid. yet at the run time it does not run remaining lines of code.

Comment: I have fixed the typos . I have pasted the code in question section. The drivers are being removed . But during the run time the complete script is not being executed.( i.e, the lines after the driver removals)

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. Please try to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or as close as you can get to one. Generally, there is no need to use `Invoke-Expression` to call external programs and to enclose command arguments in parentheses.

Answer (score -2):

The issue might be that you've created a variable called $DriverID, yet you're checking if $Driverid returns true. Variable creation is case sensitive so you have two different variables here. This will return false causing the script to skip over into the else statement.

If you want "did not find any $Driverid" to be written to the display, you'll need to put "Write-Host" in front of it.

A tidied up version of your code.

```
{
    $Driverid = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PnpSignedDriver | Where-Object 
    {$_.hardware -eq $HardWare} | Select-Object InfName -ExpandProperty InfName 
    | Select-Object -Unique)

    if($Driverid)
    {  
        Invoke-Expression "D:\Users\App.exe remove $HardWare" 
        $Command= "D:\Users\App.exe dp_delete $Driverid -f" 
        Invoke-Expression $Command
    }
    else
    {   
        Write-Host "did not find any $Driverid"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The [variables are not case sensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-3.0) in PS 3.0.

Comment: From `Get-Help about_variables` cite `Variable names are not case-sensitive.`

Comment: In addition to the incorrect information about case-sensitivity, the `Write-Host` advice is misleading.

Comment: I have fixed the typos . I have pasted the code in question section. The drivers are being removed . But during the run time the complete script is not being executed.( i.e, the lines after the driver removals)